# How to add to a list in key value pair object (jsx)

Tags: javascript, list, key-value

if you have a key value pair

```
 let appleLocations = [{
   "red": [],
   "blue": [],
   "green": []
  }
 ]
```

and you find locations of where they are (simple numeric identifiers), and want the key/value to eventually (after you've done the searching, each time adding 1 numeric identifier to the list) be like this:

```
 appleLocations = [
   "red": [2,4,6],
   "blue": [3,7,9,8],
   "green": [0,5]
 ]
```

the question becomes - how can you add to the initially blank and subsequently filled arrays without having to reference them first.

```
appleLocations["red"] = [appleLocations["red"], newLocationNumber]
```

returns an list with a sub-list and more sub-lists for each time it is ran, something like this...
[2, [4, [6]]]

where it be more useful to have
[2,4,6]

since it is not a "named" array, can't use the `concat` or other useful actions.

Comment: Your first code's syntax is okay; the second, not so much. Can you identify where you went wrong? You can use any array methods you want, not sure what the problem there is.

Comment: I tried a few, like concat... ```appleLocations["red"] = appleLocations["red"].concat(2)``` and I get ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined```

Comment: ... how about  *operating* the reference directly ... `appleLocations["red"].push(newLocationNumber)`?..

Comment: tried it, similar error: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined```

Comment: @Biaspoint ... which of the provided (the OP's example code) structures of `appleLocations` is the one to be used; the first or the last one? The syntax of the last is broken anyhow. Thus one has to assume the first one. Which leads to `appleLocations[0]["red"].push(newLocationNumber)`

Comment: If I use your first syntax, I'm able to do `appleLocations[0].red = appleLocations[0].red.concat(2)`, and `appleLocations[0].red` contains `[2]`.

Comment: What happens if you initialize it first? `appleLocations["red"] = [];` Then push items into it.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I'll re-write it, my intention is that the second one is "what we want"...

Comment: The second one is invalid.

Comment: @Biaspoint ... the second example remained unchanged, thus it still is invalid.

Comment: @HereticMonkey that will work... or alternatively I could remove the initial [ ] around the initial  ``` appleLocations``` call and then the concat and/or push will work without the ```[0]``` requirement... if you want to write it up I can select it as the answer, or I'll re-word it for clarity and answer it.

Comment: I'll write it up.

Comment: @Biaspoint ... the answer to this questions leads to the correct approach ... Does the OP want `appleLocations` to be an array of *color-items* or just a single *color-type*? ... `[ { "red": [], "blue": [], "green": [] } /*, more items */ ]`versus `{ "red": [], "blue": [], "green": [] }`

Comment: I'm equally confused about the input structure, but not about the solution, which will employ either the spread operator or array.push()

Comment: @PeterSeliger - I was trying to simplify to make the question easier to understand/answer, I had reasons to prefer the former, but see the better approach with the later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two choices here. Keep your original syntax and access the single element in your array to get to the properties you want to change:

```js
 let appleLocations = [{
   "red": [],
   "blue": [],
   "green": []
  }
 ];
 
 appleLocations[0].red = appleLocations[0].red.concat(2);
 console.log(appleLocations[0].red);
 console.log(appleLocations);
```

Or, modify your second syntax to be correct syntax for an object and access the properties as you usually would. I'm using the spread syntax here just to show there are other ways of adding elements to the array:

```js
let appleLocations = {
   "red": [2,4,6],
   "blue": [3,7,9,8],
   "green": [0,5]
};

// A different syntax just to show what's possible
appleLocations = {
  ...appleLocations,
  red: [...appleLocations.red, 10],
};

console.log(appleLocations.red);
console.log(appleLocations);
```

Comment: @Biaspoint ... Thus the shortest way of achieving the OP's goal actually is `appleLocations.red.push(10)`. Any approach above is just syntactic overkill.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Sure. But my answers tend to be less about the number of characters and more about opening the possibilities. For instance, using spread syntax would be especially helpful if you receive data for all three varieties at once. Minifiers will make the code short enough.

Comment: It's not about having short code. It is about costs, the amount of operations which come with e.g. spread operation(s) and/or accessing and reassigning the reference (twice). And it also is about understanding the code. One has to read it very carefully and more than just once in order to figure that all the fuss is simulating a simple `push`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger And if the user finds that this code is the bottleneck of their application, they are free to use different techniques. Also, there's an "Add Another Answer" button right down there waiting for you to press it...

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use flat() function for arrays

Comment: huh, nice... I'll give it a shot, seems like a correction to the symptom but might help in the short term.  Flat looks like I'll have to assign it to another variable to make use of it and then assign it back to the key:value pair.

Comment: @Biaspoint ... this one won't work either since you do not access the property of an array's color item correctly.